# During a workflow, calculated fields are not updated. Can this be done?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

**Szenario:**

Let's say we have a list with these fields:

- **L:** lookup
- **T1:** text
- **T2:** text
- **C:** calculated field with formula "=[T1] & [T2]"

And we have a workflow which does this:

1. Update Field T1 with the value of the lookup column
2. Update Field T2 with the value of the calculated field C

**Now the Problem:**

It seems that the calculated field C does not get updated properly during the workflow.

Since in Step 1, the field T1 is updated, I've expected that the field C would automatically be changed in Step 2. But this is not the case. Can this behaviour be changed?

Answer (score 1):

Calculated field updates the value when you save an item OR when you change the calculation in the field setting.

You can change you workflow ,like this:

1. Update Field T1 with the value of the lookup column
2. Update Field T2 with the value of [T1] & [T2]

or

1. Update Field T1 with the value of the lookup column
2. Call item.Update()
3. Update Field T2 with the value of the calculated field C

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be change. However you could also set the C value in the workflow...